# Android App not working on TLS 1.2

Tags: android, ssl, tls1.2

I have my Android App on production. Earlier we were using TLS 1.0 to connect the app to the server and it was working fine. Recently we upgraded the TLS to 1.2 and our app seems to stop connecting the server. My app min and max supported version are given below:

```
android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="21"
```

Everything is working fine for iOS app, I am only facing this issue in case of android. How do I make it work?

**Edit:**

I did little digging and found that the android device is not trusting the certificate: Following are the certificate info from the link which my app connects to:

[image]
**Certificate info on iPhone Chrome Browser**

[image]
**Certificate info on Android Chrome Browser**

I will update the logs as soon as I have access to those.

Comment: Can you provide the LogCat log from the time of error?

Comment: @IdanAdar I don't have access to logs right now, I will update the question with logs tomorrow. But I have updated the question with the info I find. Can you think of something what could cause the android device not to trust the certificate while the same is trusted in iPhone?

Comment: Because you are getting this error in Chrome as well, this does not sound related to MFPF.  See more here:   http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/52834/what-exactly-does-it-mean-when-chrome-reports-no-certificate-transparency-infor

Comment: If I read correctly it seems like the rtust store on the android device does not include any root certificate for the one you are using (i.e. you have difference in trust stores). GlobalSign organisation seems to be a bit less popular than e.g. Verisign. Overall I would recommend to not use the default trust stores of the devices, but rather ship the specific certificates you rely on otgether with the app (thus you will also be able to pin your certificate, rather than trusing just any verisign certificate).

Comment: @BorisStrandjev Yes, I figured this is happening but couldn't understand why it was happening. Later yesterday night suddenly my device starts to trust that certificate and that error went away. But what I could't understand is how it happened automatically?

Comment: Can you please try with another device - I wonder whether the error will emerge again

Comment: @BorisStrandjev I tried in almost 15 different android devices...In every device it started working. Can you think of any reason how it happened?

Comment: The reason why you have globally trusted authorities is so that you would not need to define a certificate yourself. But also the great advantage is that these certificates are defined in the default truststore of the device and they have the authority to revoke certificates if the need arraises (I beleive). The same way they have means of revoking certificates, they should be able to communicate new root certificates of  trust. This is my understanding, but I could not find any internet resource to guide me to the periodicality or tools of this udpate in the case of Android devices.